# NSAttributedString to NSData No visible @interface for 'NSAttributedString' declares the selector 'RTFDFromRange:documentAttributes:

Tags: ios, nsdata, nsattributedstring

I am trying to convert `NSAttributedString` to `NSData` using `RTFDFromRange` method. Getting this:

```
No visible @interface for 'NSAttributedString' declares the selector 'RTFDFromRange:documentAttributes:
```

What is wrong with my code?

```
NSAttributedString *val=self.textview.attributedText;
    NSData *data = [val RTFDFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, self.textview.text.length) documentAttributes:nil];
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`NSAttributedString` does not have a method called `RTFDFromRange` for iOS, but only for Mac OS X.

To convert `NSAttributedString` to `NSData` in iOS, you can try these two approaches:

#### 1. Using `initWithData`:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *val = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:data options:nil documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
```

#### 2. Using `NSKeyedArchiver`:

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: val];
```

And to convert the `NSData` back to a string:

```
NSAttributedString *val = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: data];
```

This code works on both Mac and iOS.

See the Apple docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/initWithData%3aoptions%3adocumentAttributes%3aerror%3a).

Answer (score 1):

That method is only available under Cocoa (OSX) as it's part of the [AppKit Additions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAttributedString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html) to `NSAttributedString`.

[Here's an open source category](https://github.com/mbrandonw/NSAttributedString-Encoding) that might do what you want under iOS (not personally tested, however).