# How Textview value stored after bold,italic,underline

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextview

How `textview` text value stored after `bold,italic,underline` in a `NSString`? I am newer in iOS. I am getting bold ,italic text on view but not save. This is my Code.

```
myTextView.allowsEditingTextAttributes =YES;
        NSString *tempMailBodyString= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body><div>%@</div></body></html>",myTextView.text];


- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
                       if (action == @selector(_showTextStyleOptions:)) {
                        return NO;
     }
            return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for how to use **NSAttributedString**/**NSMutableAttributedString** to add style or colour to your text ?

Then refer links 1 & 2,

1. [How do you use NSAttributedString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482346/how-do-you-use-nsattributedstring) and
2. [Apple - NSAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/index.html)

If you are looking for how to save **NSAttributedString**/**NSMutableAttributedString** in a file or Core Data ?

Then refer link 3,

3. [Archive or Unarchive NSAttributedString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25134707/nsattributedstring-to-nsdata-no-visible-interface-for-nsattributedstring-decl). You can use the Archived **NSData** to save it, and you can Unarchive the NSData to get the **NSAttributedString** back.